# How to Dynamically script viewport rect in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am wanting to dynamically allocate the display of 3 aircraft in unity according to the id of the vehicle in 3 corners of the screen and the main camera view in the top right. I am just unsure how to script the viewport rect as its a piece of the camera prefap.

[image]

---

### EDIT

To do this you have to search camera.rect and you can dynamically allocate it using a basic if statement.

```
using UnityEngine;

// Change the width of the viewport each time space key is pressed

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            // choose the margin randomly
            float margin = Random.Range(0.0f, 0.3f);
            // setup the rectangle
            cam.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.0f, 1.0f - margin * 2.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't added the If statement for my situation yet, that is why I am leaving the question opened incase someone can teach me something before I post my solution today.

Comment: Can't this be simply solved by looking into the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html)?

Comment: Yes and no. I felt this question is answered yes but knowing what you need to find it in the api and how to implement it dynamically is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Camera.rect in the api to find the documentation.

here is the simple if statement you could use

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    SplitScreen();
}
public void SplitScreen()
    {
        if (StateQueue.TryDequeue(out var stateMsg))

            if (stateMsg.ID == 9)
            {

                // choose the margin randomly
                float margin = Random.Range(0.0f, 0.3f);
                // setup the rectangle
                sensorCamera.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.25f, 1.0f - margin * 2.0f, 0.25f);
                MainCamera.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.50f, 0.0f - margin * 2.0f, 0.25f);

            }
            else if (stateMsg.ID == 10)
            { // choose the margin randomly
                float margin = Random.Range(0.0f, 0.3f);
                // setup the rectangle
                sensorCamera.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.25f, 0.0f - margin * 2.0f, 0.25f);
                MainCamera.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.50f, 0.0f - margin * 2.0f, 0.25f);

            }
            else if (stateMsg.ID == 11)
            {
                // choose the margin randomly
                float margin = Random.Range(0.0f, 0.3f);
                // setup the rectangle
                sensorCamera.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.25f, 0.25f - margin * 2.0f, 0.25f);
                MainCamera.rect = new Rect(margin, 0.50f, 0.0f - margin * 2.0f, 0.25f);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("this didnt work");
            }

        }
```